# Ошибка: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals. При использовании size

Tags: matlab

Здравствуйте. Проблема с использованием функции size. Выкидывает ошибку во время её первого использования. Фрагмент кода:

```
sz = length(group3items);

disp ('Работаем с 3-мя элементами набора');

% Добавляем достоверность в 5 столбец
for i = 1:sz
    group3items(i, 5) = group3items(i, 4)/group1items(group3items(i, 1), 2)*100;
end;

% Удаляем с малой достоверностью
ctr = 0;
while true
    for i = 1:sz
        if (group3items(i, 5) < minConf)
            ctr = ctr + 1;
            group3items(i, :) = [];
            sz = size(group3items, 1);
            break;
        end;
    end;
    if i == sz
        break;
    end;
end;
```

Ошибка дословно:

> ??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
> logicals.
>
> Error in ==> Untitled at 226
>
> sz = size(group3items, 1);

Как можно исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Как объявлено `group3items`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я как-бы сам уже понял как можно обойти эту проблему. Я решил находить количество строк матрицы так:

```
sz = length(group3items(:, 1));
```

И всё заработало.